# Why a function called from other function return 'function' is not defined

Tags: python

I have a long class with many functions and one of the functions calls a couple of functions previously written above. Python doesn't recognise the function in the function

```
class Sequence:               # Use a class called Sequence
    def __init__(self, DNA): 
        '''
        Stores original sequence
        '''
        self.DNA = DNA
    def length(self):
        '''
        That returns the length of the original sequence
        '''
        return len(self.DNA)

    def complement(self): 
        '''
        Return the complement of a seq given
        '''
        complement_dict = {"A": "T", "T": "A","G":"C","C":"G"}
        for k in  complement_dict: 

            complent_seq = self.DNA.replace(k, complement_dict[k]) 
        return complent_seq
    def reverse(self):
        '''
        Reverse a given seq
        '''
        reverse_seq = self.DNA[::-1]
        return reverse_seq
    def reverse_and_complement(self):
        '''
        Do the reverse first and then the complement
        calling the function reverse() and complement()
        '''
        First = reverse(self.DNA) # "reverse" is not define
```

To do this I have followed some tutorials but I have seen that in their examples they didn't use a class. Could be there the problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: call `self.reverse()` and dont pass anything as `reverse` function dont expect anything as arguments. `self `argument is implicit

Comment: Side note: Please check the result of your `complement` function. It doesn't return what you think. It should be something like `return ''.join(complement_dict[k] for k in self.DNA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are calling a member function, you have to use the `self` keyword to refer to it, just like you do when referring to member variables. Try this instead -
`First = self.reverse()`

Comment: Thanks alinkh2 for your help. Following your suggestion I got this TypeError: reverse() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Check the edit - I mistakingly said `self.reverse(self.DNA)`, instead of `self.reverse()`